# Fedora spin switch

Tags: fedora, xfce

I have installed Fedora 28 offitial release. I've installed xfce and removed GNOME. Than I've set lightdm as desktop login manager.
But when I've upgraded to 29 GNOME was back and the login manager was set to gdm. 
I've found that I could use different Fedora spins (like the xfce spin) and I'll get a preinstalled xfce desktop. But what about the next upgrade? Will I get GNOME DE again when I upgade to v30 and is therea way to switch to fedora xfce spin from offitial fedora without reinstall?

Comment: Is your case that you don't want LightDM and no GDM, or is it okay to have GDM and get Xfce as your desktop environment?

Comment: It is hard to predict the future and what will or will not happen in the future and you did not give details of how you installed xfce or removed gnome. My guess is you have some residual gnome packages that then pull in all of gnome as dependencies. If it is not too much work you can just do a fresh install of the xfce spin with the next upgrade. In my experience removing a DE such as gnome is difficult. Last I think with wayland lightdm has a bug, so perhaps gdm is a bug fix for many users and as such part of the upgrade even though you are not using wayland with xfce

Comment: But what if I install xfce spin fedora 29 and upgrade it next year to 30 ( or 28 upgrade to 29)? Will I get only xfce or the GNOME + gdm  will be automatically installed and set as default?

Comment: If you install from the spin iso, you will keep your spin when you perform the upgrade (I've did this from F26 with the cinnamon spin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the file /root/anaconda-ks.cfg. This is a better explained answer:

https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?310602-How-to-tell-which-spin-is-installed&s=a24df6f1448b0b03c1590a20c9d8d433&p=1765775#post1765775